# How to enable text tips for Webfonts, like one does in images using ALT?

Tags: html, responsive-design, webfonts, font-awesome

I may be looking at this wrongly, but with Image links I used ALT to show text tip for Imagelinks. However now I am using webfonts, and I love them. However I am unsure what is the recommended method for showing any text tip information, like one would do using the ALT attribute on an image.

My code is:

```
<a href="Index.htm"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a>
```

I am using the "fontawesome" library.

So what is a good approach for showing text help information when one hovers over the webfont?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply put, it can't be done using the alt attribute. You could look into a js based tooltip method though. Edit: totally misread that. You could use the title attribute on the element that uses the webfont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alt` attribute is not meant for tooltips, it is for providing a text **alternative** (when the image can’t be loaded or can’t be consumed, e.g., by search engines or blind visitors).

You probably mean the [`title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#the-title-attribute). In many desktop browsers, its content will show in a tooltip when hovering the element. (Note that some older *Internet Explorer* versions used the `alt` attribute for this, too.)

You can use the `title` attribute on any element.

```
<a href="Index.htm"><span class="fa fa-book" title="some advisory information"></span></a>
```

Note that you shouldn’t use the [`i` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element). Only use it for content that matches the definition in the specification (which doesn’t seem to be the case in your example). Use the `span` element, if no other elements is appropriate.

Also note that your example is not accessible.

Comment: Unor, thanks for this. Very useful. Is your answer now accessible?

Comment: @SamJolly: *Your code* is not accessible. It’s an empty link. It only works for user-agents with CSS support. But it’s not CSS’s job to provide *content*. So to be accessible, you should provide an alternative link content.